# API for Nest x Yale Lock

Tags: nest-device-access

It looks like only certain devices are supported in Device Access. How do I interact with unsupported devices? Specifically, I'd like to interact with my Nest x Yale lock, but I can find no API documentation anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported through the Device Access API.

Comment: Is there another API that it is supported through?

Comment: Not officially no.